# php code field name with hyphen

Tags: php

Trying to write a php mysql connect and query. It is giving a error "Notice: Use of undefined constant purchased - assumed 'purchased'" tried backticks that did not solve. Could some one tell where I need to correct.

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$port=3306;
$socket="";
$user="xxxx";
$password="xxxx";
$dbname="amazon";
$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
or die ('Could not connect to the database server' .     mysqli_connect_error());

$query = "SELECT SUM(`quantity-purchased`), DATE(`purchase-date`),Tally_SKU     FROM daily_orders GROUP BY DATE(daily_orders.`purchase-date`),Tally_SKU";


if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($quantity-purchased, $purchase-date, $Tally_SKU);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    //printf("%s, %s, %s\n", $quantity-purchased, $purchase-date,     $Tally_SKU);
}
$stmt->close();
}
//$con->close();


?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to use proper variable names. There's no need for them to be equal to your database's column names.

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($quantityPurchased, $purchaseDate, $TallySKU);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s, %s, %s\n", $quantityPurchased, $purchaseDate, $TallySKU);
    }
}
```

However, you can use hyphens in variable names, although it is **not recommended**, if you enclose them in curly brackets:

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result(${'quantity-purchased'}, ${'purchase-date'}, $Tally_SKU);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s, %s, %s\n", ${'quantity-purchased'}, ${'purchase-date'}, $Tally_SKU);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hyphens are not allowed in variable names.

Some rules for variables:

1) Variables should start only with alphabets (a-zA-Z) or underscores.

2) Variables should not contain hyphens.

3) Variables should not contain white spaces.

4) Variables should not contain any special characters other than underscores.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: Could you please guide me how to over come. changing the col name is not possible. Any other wayout

Comment: @Kanted : You should only change variable name in line `$stmt->bind_result($quantity-purchased, $purchase-date, $Tally_SKU);`